# Calculate the coordinates of one of the vertices of a rectangular triangle with data on the length of one side

Tags: trigonometry

I am using a cartesian coordinate system, and I have the coordinates of two points (red dots in the figure). By Pythagoras I can calculated the distance between those two points. However I want to know the coordinates of the green dot, which is perpendicular the side $b$, given that I know the distance $a= 80.$ I cannot find a way to calculate the coordinates of the green point. Any suggestions will be most welcomed.

[image]

Comment: You would either need to know the angle measure of BAC/BCA or the side lengths of two of the sides of your triangle to be able to find the coordinate of the third dot. It takes three points to determine a triangle, so if you only know the location of two of those points, you could form infinitely many triangles.

Comment: Given that side $a$ is perpendicular to side $b,$ there is enough other information in the diagram to solve the problem. The linked question has answers that show how.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$, then you have $x_3 = x_1$ and you have that

$y_3 = y_1 + a = y_1+80$

Then your point is $(x_3,y_3)=(x_1, y_1+80)$